# how to code the new material design textfields in android (editText)

Tags: android, design-patterns, material-design

How do you code these new material design text fields in android?

EditText doesn't look like that, right?

https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such design you can try using the [androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) set of libraries. Simultaneously with package changes, they rolled out a set of new widgets, styles and so on. So in your case you should have used an EditText from the androidX library and a `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` style

Comment: I ended up using a TextInputLayout and what you mentioned, thanks